# How to access DataSource object without 'java:/comp/env/' prefix in lookup method?

Tags: java, datasource, jndi

Since JNDI resource named **jdbc/myDB** is declared inside Tomcat *server/context.xml*, I can access the DataSource in the following way:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
DatSource dataSource = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB");
```

Is it possible, with a config trick in .xml , to get it just by:

```
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
```

without ***java:/comp/env/*** prefix in *lookup* method?

Comment: Why? What's the problem with doing it the way it's documented to work?

Comment: @EJP, I am creating a lib which is going to be consumed by several  java applications of which some run on Tomcat and others on Glassfish. The lib itself performs some db operations using datasource of consumer apps.I am just wondering if it is possible , in unique way, to get the datasource regardless of the app server since `dataSource = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jdbc/myDB");` works in case of Glassfish, but for Tomcat 'java:/comp/env/` prepender is needed.I would like to avoid double check whilst initializing 'dataSource' and get rid of exception log of lookup call.